Batch renaming bones - without number sequence at the end
I need assistance. I am trying to batch rename the bones but its not working as intended.
When I batch rename the bones from e.g. DEF_CHEST.L to ORG_CHEST.L, they are all replaced with numbers at the end like this ORG_CHEST.L.001 and I don't want the numbers. When I remove .001 at the end, it is replaced with ,002 then .003.... If I use "Strip Character - Digits - end", the digits are replaced with two dots at the end instead. How can I remove everything and remain with .L or .R at the end.
I will appreciate your assistance.
Thank you.

Normally this only happens if an object with that name already exists.
This is also true for deleted objects (which might only be "really" deleted if you leave Blender or purge them).
So you should also check in the outliner -> blender file whether the name of the objects is already in use.
